# Django: Getting error when unit testing the UserProfile

Tags: django, unit-testing

I keep getting a unit test error in Django, which I don't understand.

**full error message:**

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
.................................................................................E.......................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................s........................................................................
======================================================================
ERROR: test_site_profile_not_available (django.contrib.auth.tests.models.ProfileTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/tests/models.py", line 29, in test_site_profile_not_available
    del settings.AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 215, in __delattr__
    delattr(self._wrapped, name)
AttributeError: AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 418 tests in 26.548s

FAILED (errors=1, skipped=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

**Update:**

I have inserted the full error message and even cut down the test to a minimum:

```
class ContactModelTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        ctype = ContactType.objects.create()
        ctype.contact_type= "test1"
        ctype.save()  

def test_get_contacts_user1(self):        
        ctype = ContactType.objects.all()
```

why is this happening?

Comment: what line is this happening on?

Comment: ahh it seems to be a bug: https://github.com/tfausak/bauble/issues/24 solution is apparently `Fix #24; don't run Django's contrib app tests. Also skip tests for django-* packages, like compressor.` What does it mean? Where can I set this?

Comment: I found the solution: `python manage.py test my_app my_app.ContactModelTest`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you don't have declared `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE` in your settings. As [Django documentation indicates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users), you need to declare it by saying your application and UserProfile Model you're using, like

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = "accounts.UserProfile"
```

Comment: No, I have set it. I even commented it out and I got a different error message. This is a bug as I hinted in my comments. Should be fixed in the next version. I'll post the full answer soon